# Stateless EJB, exception handling issue, container swallowing exception

Tags: java, exception, ejb-3.0, rmi, weblogic12c

I have two Stateless Session Beans. Call Hierarchy is like:

MyClass-> UserManagerBean -> BookManagerBean

MyClass is obtaining UserManagerBean remotely by JNDI look up.
In turn UserManagerBean is getting BookManagerBean remotely by JNDI look up.
 BookManagerBean is throwing BookException.

**Issue:**
I am able to see log before throwing exception from BookManagerBean, but when I am catching this exception in UserManagerBean, thread goes somewhere and never comes in catch block of  UserManagerBean.  Looks like container swallows this exception. This result in STUCK thread.

**Note:**  Surprisingly, same code works on 5 other WLS instances, but gives problem on only one server. Do you think of any weblogic configuration around this issue?

```
    public class MyClass {
    public void findBook(Long bookId) throws Exception{
    try{
        UserManagerBean userManager =  (UserManager) JNDIServiceLocator.getInstance().getRemoteObject(jndiName, 'UserManager' );
        userManager.find(bookId);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.log("Exception in MyClass.findBook"); // Thread does not come back to this point. This logger is not getting printed
        throw e;
    }
```

UserManagerBean is as follow:

```
 @Stateless(mappedName ="UserManager")
@Remote(UserManager.class)
public class UserManagerBean {
public Book findBook(Long bookId) throws Exception{
    try{
        BookManagerBean bookManager =  (BookManagerBean) JNDIServiceLocator.getInstance().getRemoteObject(jndiName, 'BookManager' );
        bookManager.find(bookId);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.log("Exception in UserManagerBean.findBook"); // **** Thread does not come back to this point. This logger is not getting printed

        throw e;
    }
}
```

BookManagerBean Class is like below:

```
@Stateless(mappedName ="BookManager")
@Remote(BookManagerBean .class)
public class BookManagerBean {

public Book findBook(Long bookId) throws Exception{
    try{
        //Logic to find Book
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.log("Exception");
        throw e;
    }
}   

}
```

**This works:**
If I change the code in UserManagerBean to create bean using new operator, I get the exception thrown from  BookManagerBean.

```
BookManagerBean bookManager  = new BookManagerBean(); 
bookManager.find(bookId);
```

Comment: This code works as-is on one WLS instance in production but doesn't work on other. Can you think of any weblogic configuration related to this?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to create your own Custom Exception and annotate it with

[javax.ejb.ApplicationException.](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/ApplicationException.html)

-Amit